# Publishing ASP.NET MVC web app and console application at the same time using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, console-application, publish

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

In my project I have an ASP.NET MVC web application and a console application. When I deploy the ASP.NET MVC app to my server, I can just use the "Publish" option in Visual Studio 2019.

I then have to set my console application to "start up project", build that in release mode and then copy the `bin\release` folder manually to my server.

Is there any script or code that I can put into the ASP.NET MVC application build events in Visual Studio that when I publish the main ASP.NET MVC web application it also publishes the console application?

Comment: Could specify and tag the version of VS you're using.

Comment: @phuzi i've added that now. It is VS 2019.